# Why my event listener is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem where I can't call my function form "js" file. I have function like this where I chech for special character in input of name.

```
function specijalniZnakovi(event){
        if(((event.keyCode === 33) || (event.keyCode === 35) || (event.keyCode === 39) || (event.keyCode === 63))){
           event.returnValue = false;
           alert("Nedozvoljeni znak!");
           return;
        }
        event.returnValue = true;
     }
```

And I am calling function like this:

```
document.getElementById("ime").addEventListener("keypress", specijalniZnakovi(event));
```

And this is my input:

> input type="text" id="ime" name="tekst" size="15" maxlength="15" required="required" placeholder="Ime i prezime">

When I put it like this it's working perfectly, but I need it call from "js" file because my professor says so. :(

> ```
>            <input type="text" id="ime" name="tekst" size="15" maxlength="15" required="required" placeholder="Ime i prezime" onkeypress="specijalniZnakovi(event)">
> ```

Comment: You have an extra open bracket in your conditional statement

Comment: It should be `....addEventListener("keypress", specijalniZnakovi)` instead of `....addEventListener("keypress", specijalniZnakovi(event))`. The second parameter should be a reference to a function not the result of calling the function.